# Where to override current_user helper method of devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, devise

How can i override **current_user** of **devise gem.** 
Actually I need to add web services for mobile-app.

Currently devise is managing session and 'current_user' for web-application.

Now Mobile app will send user_id to the server.  I need to override current user like this

```
def current_user
  if params[:user_id].blank?
    current_user
  else
    User.find(params[:user_id])
  end   
end
```

Should I need to modify devise gem as plugin ? or something else ?
Kindly explain in detail as I am new in rails.

Kind regards,

Comment: yikes... so, are you saying when a mobile agent sends up a user_id you'll just trust it?

Comment: also some authentication secret key

Comment: Devise will handle that token_authenticatable - just passing authentication_token up, no need for user_id.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to the module [Devise::Controllers::Helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb), `current_user` (together with all other devise helpers) is added to ApplicationController, which means that you can override it in this way:

```
# in application_controller.rb

def devise_current_user
  @devise_current_user ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :user)
end

def current_user
  if params[:user_id].blank?
    devise_current_user
  else
    User.find(params[:user_id])
  end   
end
```

Comment: Error on the "alias_method" row: undefined_method 'current_user' for class ApplicationController (NameError), when starting up my environment. If I comment it out, boot up, and uncomment, it works fine. Got a fix?

Comment: Frexuz, try replacing the alias_method with something like:

def devise_current_user { @devise_current_user ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :user) }

Comment: is this thread-safe? I'm getting nil errors in weird points in controllers after authentication on MRI.

Comment: why alias current_user instead of calling super?

Comment: `alias_method` is better than calling `super` in case you'd actually need to acccess the original `current_user`. You may need it at some point (eg. `if current_user != devise_current_user #etc.`).

Comment: What for @devise_current_user? What is that?

Answer (score 6):

The other answer suggesting aliasing the method is actually not the best solution. Doug English's comment is the best solution:

```
# In ApplicationHelper
def devise_current_user
   @devise_current_user ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :user)
end
```

Here's the reason:

Suppose you're including your ApplicationHelper in your controller. If you need a method in your ApplicationHelper that relies on devise_current_user, given the alias solution inside the controller, you're out of luck.

But with the explicit method definition above, you can move the definition to the helper and call it from other methods and you still get to include it in the controller.

This is useful, for example, when you're developing a user impersonation solution and you need to show two different users in the view, one for the real admin (devise_current_user) and the other, the impersonated user (current_user).

Comment: Indeed you are right. Please mention that the following should be included in the `ApplicationController `: `include ApplicationHelper`. Otherwise, `devise_current_user` becomes unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Limbo-Peng's answer is great, but can be improved a little to make sure only admins can do this:

You'll need to also define a `is_admin?` method or `is_admin` attribute on the User class.

You may also want to use a different key than `user_id`, so it will never conflict with your regular parameters.

```
# to impersonate another user, e.g. for customer support
# only admins can do this..
#
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
def current_user
  if ! params[:user_id].blank? \
     && devise_current_user && devise_current_user.is_admin? 
    User.find(params[:user_id])
  else
    devise_current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we can trust our session data (which relies on whether you put user input in there without proper authorization or not), this might work as a Concern:

```
module Concerns
  module ControllerWithImpersonation
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      helper_method :devise_current_user
    end

    def current_user
      if session[:impersonated_user_id].blank?
        devise_current_user
      else
        User.find(session[:impersonated_user_id])
      end
    end

    def devise_current_user
      @devise_current_user ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :user)
    end

  end
end
```

I'm using this in a project for now.

A minor question (in the answer, sorry) ... should I be aware of any changes in Devise or Warden that make `devise_current_user` above outdated?