# Devise: override current_user (set different Class for user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to do this:

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    if params[:user].blank?
      puts "!found user"
      devise_current_user
    else
      puts "found user"
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
      return detect_role(user)
    end
  end

  def detect_role(user)
    roles = user.roles_name
    user = if roles.include?("mentor")
             user.becomes(Mentor)
           elsif !roles.include?("admin") && !roles.include?("mentor")
             user.becomes(Student)
           else
             user
           end
  end
end
```

but still does not go out to override current_user

log:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0a5fb593b020b16a0cd2ae9d539b92a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to override current\_user helper method of devise gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349606/where-to-override-current-user-helper-method-of-devise-gem)

Comment: I want to override User to different class, but always got User class

Comment: If not getting a user class this is nor a devise problem, but probably a problem in your User retrieval logic. Can you show how you coded these subclasses and the user class? How are their relations?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1e09453c6cc3dd0c17e4faec1aca271

Comment: So you do have a `type` column which determines the `User` class?

Comment: Just be clear, the problem is `#detect_role` does not return a user of the right class, which should be one of the subclasses based on the roles, right?  How do you know it's not working? The log you showed didn't hit the correct branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    user = if params[:user].blank?
             devise_current_user
           else
             User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
           end
    detect_role(user) if !user.blank?
  end

  def detect_role(user)
    roles = user.roles_name
    user = if roles.include?("mentor")
             user.becomes(Mentor)
           elsif !roles.include?("admin") && !roles.include?("mentor")
             user.becomes(Student)
           else
             user
           end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> super

keyword and then right your override code like this;

```
def current_user
  super
  ----your code goes here ---
end
```

Comment: Added `super` but it did not help log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/688eeb1568f359bd2ad98e735d4972e7